# Embed audio in gltf file?

Tags: modeling, audio, gltf

Does anyone know how to embed audio into a gltf or glb file?

If this isn't too giddily optimistic a question then I'd love to know how to do this! Currently using Blender although I'm happy to buy whatever software this requires.

Also, I tried adding a speaker in Blender and an audio file in video editor then exporting onto sketchfab but no sound. Also tried it with an mp4 with sound uv'd onto the material. still nada..

Any ideas?

Best wishes, Dan

Comment: I don't think the glb/gltf format supports audio at all. https://docs.fileformat.com/3d/gltf/

Comment: Actually, there is a proposed audio extension called [KHR_audio](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/2137) that is being considered currently by Khronos.  But it could be many months before such a standard is agreed upon by all members, voted and ratified, and implemented in the Blender glTF exporter.

Comment: While I don’t think this is a bad question, it’s not really exactly related to Blender, but more to the GLTF format. I suppose if the GLTF format did support audio but you were having trouble getting blender to export with that, it definitely would be about Blender, so you may not have known this.

Comment: Thanks John Eason and emackey for your contributions to this thread. Very useful and much appreciated!